# overlayPanel to show img style only

Tags: css, angular, primeng

[image: content move away]
Hi,
I have overlay that I want to use only to show img (without style for overlay), the way I code to cancel the width\height etc not working so much as you see..
any suggestions?

```
<p-overlayPanel #op [style]="{'border':'none' ,'height': '0','width': '0'}">
                <img class="note-btn" src="assets/images/fo_opinion_tooltip.svg" width="800" height="400" alt="note-notified"  />
              </p-overlayPanel>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The picture u sent not very clear but if you want to remove whitespaces and shadow

use :

```
[style]="{'box-shaodw':'none' ,'padding':'0!important' ,'border':'none' ,'height': '0','width': '0'}"
```